# gnuplot - Set transparent histogram

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I'm trying to superimpose two histograms and I need the second one (blue in the image) to be transparent so the one below it can be seen:

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnuplot << EOF

set term postscript portrait color enhanced 
set output 'test.ps'
set size ratio 1
set multiplot
set size 0.5,0.5

n=20    #number of intervals
max=1.0 #max value
min=0.0    #min value
width=(max-min)/n        #interval width
hist(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)+width/2.0

set boxwidth width*0.9
set xrange [0:1]
plot "/path_to_file" u (hist(\$1,width)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes lc rgb "black" lt 1 lw 0.5 notitle fs solid 0.5, \
"/path_to_file" u (hist(\$2,width)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes  notitle fs transparent pattern 4 noborder lc rgb "blue" lt 1 lw 0.5

EOF
```

Here's a file that can be used with the above code: http://pastebin.com/5qpFHgtZ

Comment: haha sorry for that. Removed the `awk` bit since it wasn't really necessary and added a data file.

Comment: I think you lost a `plot` in your script.  I'll give this a shot and see what I can do with it...

Comment: Yes I did, I'll correct it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I change the terminal to `png` (or `pdf` or `pdfcairo`) (e.g `set term png enhanced`), I get a plot which looks correct.

However, gnuplot seems to think that `postscript` should create a transparent plot (see table below, taken from `help transparent`).  So, my diagnosis is that it is either a bug in gnuplot, or a bug in the documentation.

```
   terminal   solid pattern    pm3d
   --------------------------------
   gif           no     yes      no
   jpeg         yes      no     yes
   pdf          yes     yes     yes
   png    TrueColor   index     yes
   post          no     yes      no
   svg          yes      no     yes
   win          yes     yes     yes
   wxt          yes     yes     yes
   x11           no     yes      no
```

Comment: You are correct, it does work with a `png` terminal. How could I get a high quality output from this terminal? I guess I'll be using it since `postscript` won't handle transparencies.

Comment: @Gabriel -- p.s. I filed a [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3567035&group_id=2055&atid=102055)

Comment: @Gabriel -- I also tried it in the `pdf` and `pdfcairo` terminals and it worked.  They may be more "high quality" if you have either of those terminals installed.

Comment: Thank you so much! The `pdfcairo` terminal is far better than the `png` in terms of quality.

Comment: @Gabriel -- If you're interested, Ethen Merritt (I think the lead developer for gnuplot) posted a workaround for your problem in the postscript terminal.  (See the previously mentioned bug report).  He doesn't think that the issue will be fixed in gnuplot 4.6.1 (the next release, due soon), but there is a workaround and it doesn't seem too bad.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I'll be sure to give it a try although your `pdfcairo` workaround is doing quite well so far :)